# Consuming a web service in C# from Java client, can't detect classes

Tags: java, c#, eclipse, web-services, soap

I'm trying to consume a web service written in C# in VS from a java client in Eclipse. In my controller I try to call a method from one of the classes written in C#. My problem is that it seems like the classes can't be detected, how can I solve that?

First time working with these kinds of projects, so you'll have to excuse a somewhat poor explanation. Posting code to make it somewhat easier to understand

Heres one example, it says that "Customer can't be resolved to a type"

```
// CUSTOMER
    public void populateCustomerTable() {
        Customer[] customers = null;

        try {
            customers = proxy.getCustomers();
        } catch (RemoteException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        broCodeFrame.getCustomerTable().addCustomerBatch(customers);
    }
```

I've made sure that the Web Service Client is updated, but seems to do nothing.
[image: Screenshot of all the classes I have in Eclipse]
[image: Screenshot of the classes in VS/C# that I need to access]

Comment: you cant use a C# class from java. You need a java class.

Comment: @GyroGearless Shouldn't the C# classes be translated to java classes through the web service client?, or do I misunderstand it? I been following the steps my professor provides but he kind of leaves that part out